# Play 2 - How to use a library included via sbt

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, dependencies, sbt

I just add a sbt dependency to my Play 2 project:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
   "org.markdownj" % "markdownj" % "0.3.0-1.0.2b4"    
)
```

How can I now use this library in my controllers & models in Play 2. I just can't figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage in templates:

```
@Html(new com.petebevin.markdown.MarkdownProcessor().markdown("This is a *simple* test."))
```

Usage in a controller/model:

```
import com.petebevin.markdown.MarkdownProcessor
val textInMarkdown = /* where ever your text comes from */
val htmlCode: String = new MarkdownProcessor().markdown(textInMarkdown)
```

May be it is helpful to generate javadocs (bash):

```
git clone https://github.com/myabc/markdownj.git
cd markdownj/core
mvn javadoc:javadoc #this may take a while, loading lots of dependencies
#open markdownj/core/target/site/apidocs/index.html
```

Be open for other markdown processors.

Comment: Works great! Thanks! How did figure out the path `com.petebevin.markdown.MarkdownProcessor`? I tried `org.markdownj.MarkdownProcessor` because that is the name in the repository. Would be great to know if I add any other dependencies.

Comment: I checked out the project and used 'grep -r "MarkdownProcessor" .' to find the definition of that class and it's package declaration. Before your question I never heard about markdownj.

Comment: Thanks! Still seems quite a lot of work to me to only figure out the class path.